# How to get the latest date for each user id in a table

Tags: sql

This is what I have so far, and it is pulling every single check for that Id. I need the latest checkdt for each Id. What am I missing?

```
SELECT e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.VoidDT
    ,MAX(ec.CheckDT) AS FirstChecktDT
FROM PR_Employee e
JOIN PR_Employeecheck ec ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id
WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
    AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.CheckDT
    ,ec.VoidDT
ORDER BY employeenumber
    ,CheckDT DESC
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the `GROUP BY` clause you use columns from the table `PR_Employeecheck` so you are not grouping by employee but by employee and each matching row of the join.
Instead you can join the table `PR_Employee` to a query that uses `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to return the last date and remove the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.VoidDT
    ,ec.CheckDT AS FirstChecktDT
FROM PR_Employee e
JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY CheckDT DESC) rn
  FROM PR_Employeecheck
) ec ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id
WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
  AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
  AND ec.rn = 1
ORDER BY e.employeenumber
    ,ec.CheckDT DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

### Group by Columns

The problem is your `group by`. You should use only the `id` column.

Otherwise you are asking for the maxmum CheckDT grouped by the combination of all those columns.

```
SELECT e.Id
    MAX(ec.CheckDT) AS FirstChecktDT
FROM PR_Employee e
JOIN PR_Employeecheck ec ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id
WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
    AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.Id;
```

Try the above.

### So how do you get the remaining columns?

You can join the result of the `(id, maxCheckId)` with the whole table.

Forgive me, I havn't tested the below query in an actual DB.

**Example using intermediate alias:**

```
select * from 
(
SELECT e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.VoidDT
    ,MAX(ec.CheckDT) AS FirstChecktDT
FROM PR_Employee e
JOIN PR_Employeecheck ec ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id
WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
    AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
) data1 join
( 
SELECT e.Id
        MAX(ec.CheckDT) AS FirstChecktDT
    FROM PR_Employee e
    JOIN PR_Employeecheck ec ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id
    WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
        AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY e.Id
) data2 on data1.id = data2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub-query to identify the maximum date, then join to that sub-query:

```
SELECT 
     e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.VoidDT
    ,ec.MaxDt AS FirstChecktDT
FROM
FROM PR_Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT 
         CheckNumber
        ,VoidDT
        ,EmployeeId
        ,MAX(CheckDT) AS MaxDt
    FROM PR_Employeecheck
    WHERE CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
    ) AS ec 
    ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id 
WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
ORDER BY employeenumber
    ,CheckDT DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to find the `max(CheckDt)` for the employee record you are processing. Then you just filter to match that:

```
SELECT e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.VoidDT
    ,ec.CheckDT AS FirstChecktDT
FROM PR_Employee e
JOIN PR_Employeecheck ec ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id
WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
    AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
    AND ec.CheckDt = (SELECT max(CheckDt) FROM PR_Employeecheck WHERE id = e.EmployeeNumber)
ORDER BY employeenumber
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is, you have included `ec.CheckDT` in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. Take that out, and it should work as desired.

```
SELECT e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.VoidDT
    ,MAX(ec.CheckDT) AS FirstChecktDT
FROM PR_Employee e
JOIN PR_Employeecheck ec ON ec.EmployeeId = e.id
WHERE e.employeestatusid IN (1,4)
    AND CheckNumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.Id
    ,e.EmployeeNumber
    ,e.LastName
    ,e.FirstName
    ,ec.CheckNumber
    ,ec.VoidDT
ORDER BY employeenumber
```

Comment: This should apply regardless of SQL product, brand, version, edition, or flavor.